# How to accept multiple strings from user at same time and store them in list in python?

Tags: python

I have to accept three strings as inputs from the user at the same time and store them in list.

Suppose user enters 'a1','b1','c1'
The list should contain
Ip=['a1','b1','c1']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to @Ajax1234 ans we can also do it in this way

`x_list = raw_input().split(',')` #if string separated by comma

`x_list = raw_input().split(' ')` #is string separated by space

Answer (score 0):

You can have the user input a string containing the letters, and then split them:

```
s = input() # a1,b1,c1
ip = s.split(',')
```

Also, if you want to have the user enter only a single letter at a time, you can use list comprehension:

```
ip = [input() for i in range(3)]
```